# Show progress bar for iOS while uploading video to youtube using youtube direct lite api

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube, youtube-api

Currently I am using 
https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS
by Ibrahim Ulukaya. I have been successful in uploading videos to youtube. What I want to know is that if it is possible to check the upload progress using the same library ?

Thanks in advance.

p.s. I do not want to check the bytes sent on network as there might be background traffic from my application as well.

Regards.

Comment: Please edit your Q and post code you have tried.

Comment: I havent added my code at all. As i said; i am using the above given library. While uploading to youtube, this code is used

[service executeQuery:query
        completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                            GTLYouTubeVideo *insertedVideo, NSError *error)

But this does not give the progress rate at which the upload is happening.

Comment: Hello, Have you got any solution for this I also need to show progress bar